# The directory name <Path> is invalid | Impersonation | Windows Service

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, windows-services, impersonation, filesystemwatcher

I have a windows service which is intended to monitor a File Path and later perform some actions on the files created.

The location to be monitored is a network location on which the user I am impersonating has full access.

```
LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 3;
LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0;

string watchPath = @"\\servername\Folder\";
using (new Impersonator("UserName", "Domain", "Password"))
{
  [PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
  FSWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher(); 
  FSWatcher.Path = watchPath;  \\ POINT OF ERROR
  FSWatcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;

  FSWatcher.Filter = "*.xls";
  FSWatcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
  FSWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
  FSWatcher.IncludeSubdirectories = false;
}
```

I get an Error saying - "The directory name  is invalid"...

I have no clue what is causing this error, since the network path is accessible when I access it using the credentials manually.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to access resources on another server, then the account under which your code is running (not the impersonated account) should be configured to be able to delegate credentials.

Check this MSDN article: [Impersonation/Delegation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647248.aspx)